# Error: Compile Error: Illegal assignment from List<Lead> to lead at line 14 column 5

Tags: visualforce, lead-conversion

```
 public class ControllerLeadConvertView {
   public Id leadId;
    public String convertedAccountId ;
    public ControllerLeadConvertView(ApexPages.StandardController stdController)
   {
        leadId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('id');

    }


    public PageReference convertLead(){
    try
    {
    lead leadobj=new Lead();
    leadobj = [select id,MobilePhone,Company from lead where id =:leadId];
    Account a = new Account();
    a.Name =leadobj.Company;  
    insert a;
    PageReference newocp= new PageReference('/'+ a.Id);

     newocp.setRedirect(true);
           return newocp;

     }             
    catch(Exception e)
    {
            System.Debug('Error - ControllerLeadConvertView.convertLead - Exception [' + 

e.getMessage() + ']');
            return null;
    }         
}
}
```

vf code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead" action="{!convertLead}" extensions="ControllerLeadConvertView">
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `StandardController`:

```
public with sharing class ControllerLeadConvertView
{
    public Lead lead { get; private set; }
    public Id leadId { get; private set; }

    public ControllerLeadConvertView(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        // can remove the next two lines if fields are used on page
        List<String> toQuery = new List<String> { 'MobilePhone', 'Company' };
        if (!Test.isRunningTest()) controller.addFields(toQuery);

        this.leadId = controller.getId();
        this.lead = (Lead)controller.getRecord();
    }
}
```

You can also make your `convertLead` method more programmatic.

```
public PageReference convertLead()
{
    Account someAccount;
    // set up your record as needed
    try
    {
        insert someAccount;
    }
    catch (DmlException dmx)
    {
        // this step is really important
        ApexPages.addMessages(dmx);
        return null;
    }
    // the below methodology is best practice
    // when constructing a detail view PageReference
    return new ApexPages.StandardController(someAccount).view();
}
```